# Is there a graceful way to upgrade from Twitter Bootstrap 3 rc1 to the stable release?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been having a good time working with Bootstrap 3 rc1, but now the stable release is out and it's even BETTER. I tried swapping out the files but many things break. I read the summary of changes [here](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/08/13/bootstrap-3-rc2/) but it's a bit vague and a lot seems to have changed between rc1 and rc2. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a straight-forward guide to making that transition.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a definitive answer for this, so here's a collection of what I encountered...

1. All `.col-*` classes need to be replaced with `.col-sm-*` (they also added `.col-md-*`).
2. If you're using glyphicons, they're font files now, so you'll need to make sure those files are in the right place.
3. In previous version, I had `.row` classes wrapped around things which behaved weirdly when I upgraded. I ended up stripping out and `.row` classes that aren't parents of `.col-*-*`s.
4. `navbar` component was completely redone, so if you use that you'll have to just redo it.

These 4 things, covered just about everything I encountered, but I'm still working on this so I'll update later if I run into more stuff big stuff.

Comment: So much for being a release candidate. Those are some massively breaking changes.

Comment: Yup. It took me by surprise too.